# Only delete files but not folders with rm

Tags: command-line, rm

I have a directory like this:

```
<folder1>
<folder2>
<folder3>
file1
file2
file3
```

What is the rm command like that removes only file1, file2, file3 but leaves folder1, folder2 and folder3 and their content untouched?

Comment: is there any pattern or you just want to remove all files in that directory leaving the directories as it is ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rm` won't delete directories by default. So in your example, **assuming you're in the parent directory** and those are all the files, all you need is:

```
rm *
```

**That's a dangerous command.** If you forget where you are, a command like that can wipe out important `$HOME` files, wipe out a load of photos, cancel Christmas, etc, etc, etc. Make sure you know what `*` is selecting before you run it. `echo *` is a good way to test the expansion.

A sane person presented with `file1 file2 file3` might run `rm file*` or `rm file{1..3}` to use some of Bash's expansion code and not catch any stragglers you hadn't thought of in the crossfire.

---

To delete directories you need to specify either:

- `-d` to delete empty directories, or
- `-r` to recursively delete files and their directories.

Comment: If you wanted to be slightly more selective with the files that are removed, [bash wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x1655.htm) let you do that. For example `rm file*` will delete ever file beginning with "file"

Comment: what if I want to recursively delete all files but not delete any folders it encounters?

Answer (score 2):

As @Oli said in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/665535/367165)

> rm won't delete directories by default.

---

But you could also use `find`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm "{}" \;
```

or with a search pattern

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "a*" -exec rm "{}" \;
```

---

*Example*

```
% tree
.
├── a
├── b
├── bar
│   ├── a
│   └── b
└── foo
    ├── a
    └── b

%  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm "{}" \;

% tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── a
│   └── b
└── foo
    ├── a
    └── b
```

or with a search pattern

```
% find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "a*" -exec rm "{}" \;

% tree                                                  
.
├── b
├── bar
│   ├── a
│   └── b
└── foo
    ├── a
    └── b
```